# How are non-gmail accounts shown in Google Code SVN repositories?

Tags: svn, google-code

I'm about to migrate a project to Google Code, and for that I'm changing our SVN repository to display the new author names.

I know that gmail based Google Code accounts only display the username of the user in the svn:author property. So for a Code account `example@gmail.com`, the SVN author name would be `example`.

Now I have some project members, who don't own a gmail address but have some other email as their Google Code account name. What SVN author name will be used for those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out: For non-gmail accounts, it's the full email address.